# How to measure ARM performance?

Tags: c, arm

I'm working with optimizing a software and wants to measure the performance. So I am currently simulating an ARM platform with OVP (open virtual platform) and I get the statistics as simulation time and simulated instructions.

My question is, why is the simulated instructions different everytime I run the software (different, but close proximity)? Should it not be the same everytime? Is it not like this , the software that I write in C will be compiled into ARM assembler instructions, and each time the software runs, the simulated instructions will be how many time these ARM assembler instructions run? It should be the same everytime?

How should I measure performance? Take 10 samples of simulated instructions and get the average?

Comment: Some systems you can expect to be within one clock tick of the measuring device for each run, for some systems there are dynamics involved that dont allow that to happen.  And it could be related to what you are doing anyway.  Are you running embedded or on top of an operating system?  What kind of software are you talking to peripherals, over a network, etc?

Comment: the number of instructions may vary depending on what you are doing, lets say you have a loop of 20 instructions polling for some event or peripheral to finish something.  If from one run to the next you just miss an event and have to run the loop again there is a 20 instruction difference.  Have that happen a few to many times per simulation and that can add up to noticeable differences.  If you tailor the code and the test to something that can never rely on outside events and that is by design going to execute the same path, then yes it should be the same each time.

Comment: What kind of performance are you trying to measure? CPU, memory, IO, network? If we are talking about cpu, bogomips might be worth a try/look.

Comment: A simulator is not the same as an emulator! Your simulator is probably converting the ARM instructions to whatever the host is running (x86, say) and then executing that. An emulator wouldn't do the conversion, it would have code to pretend to do the ARM instructions. Emulating is slower than simulating (once the conversion is done). I'm not sure a simulator would give you useful results.

Comment: I don't know what your platform is, but if it's a custom embedded system without OS, then a common profiling approach is to toggle some LED in your code and connect an oscilloscope to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience in a real (non-simulated) ARM, if I take cycle counts for a section of the code the number of cycles will vary, this is because:

- There can be context switches in the middle of your executing code.
- The initial state of the CPU may be different upon entering the code section. (e.g. the content of the pipeline, branch prediction etc.)
- The cache state will be different on entry to the code section.
- External factors such as other hardware accessing external memory.

Due to all these, taking an average (plus some other statistical measures) is really the only practical approach for real hardware and a real OS.  In a good simulator some of these factors or potentially eliminated.

On some real chips (or if supported by the simulator) the ARM [Performance Monitoring Unit](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4237.html) can be useful.

If you're coding for the Cortex A8 [this](http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php) is a cool online cycle counter that can really help you squeeze more performance out of your code.